# Filter markers by radius.

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm doing an activity that contains a map. The activity shows several markers. I want to achieve that the user can pick o select the radius to show or not show that markers. Did you do that? Can you upload designs o best practices? I don't want code, I'm a senior android developer.

Mi best approach is an action bar icon that opens a dialog with a seek 
bar.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it using gestures on the map. When the user clicks on the map and drags I would draw a circle centered on the current location and the radius would be the distance between the DOWN position and the current DRAG position and I would show the markers within the circle.

It's easy to understand but it can be difficult to find the first time, so you may need to train your users if you want to use this approach.

Comment: It's good but I have that when the user clicks on the map I refresh the markers based on the new position.

Comment: Then it's better. If the user clicks, refresh the markers drawing a given (predefined the first time) circle. If the user drags, refresh the markers drawing the circle proposed in my solution